# How to visualize a set of identical flows?

Tags: highcharts

I have data which can be interpreted as *from `a` to `b` to `c`*:

```
[
  ["hello", "world", "10"],
  ["hello", "world", "10"],
  ["hello", "wazaa", "10"],
  ["bonjour", "wazaa", "30"],
]
```

The same flow can be repeated (first two examples) and any combination is possible.

A chart which could be used to show these flows is [`parallel-coordinates`](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parallel-coordinates): there is always the same number of columns and each flow can be tracked (as opposed to [`sankey`](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sankey-diagram) which aggregates each input column).

The problem I have with `parallel-coordinates` is that multiple identical entries will stack (I guess) and the fact there are duplicates will not appear.

**Is there a way to change the width of the line to indicate that several identical data lines were used?** Or to provide a count of the identical entries which would be reflected in the width (or, worst case, color)?

Comment: You would probably have to get the count through whatever is serving up your numbers. For example, if you're using `SQL`, have a `COUNT(*)` somewhere for whatever you are grouping the series by. That way each data point will have that value.

Comment: @CodeAssist: counting is not a problem. Visually making sense of that number is (via the line width, or color)

Comment: You can set colors dynamically with another array, either pulled from the original dataset or created separately. Then you could have a custom legend somewhere that shows the range of colors. You will have to do a little bit of custom coding here.

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your data and set higher `lineWidth` value for series with repeating data:

```
var series = [{
            data: [0, 0, 10]
        },
        {
            data: [0, 0, 10]
        },
        {
            data: [0, 0, 10]
        },
        {
            data: [0, 0, 10]
        },
        {
            data: [0, 1, 10]
        },
        {
            data: [1, 1, 30]
        }
    ],
    j = series.length - 1,
    dataLength = series[0].data.length,
    i;

for (; j > 0; j--) {
    i = 0;
    for (; i < dataLength; i++) {
        if (series[j].data[i] === series[j - 1].data[i]) {
            if (i === dataLength - 1) {
                series[j - 1].lineWidth = series[j].lineWidth ?
                    series[j].lineWidth + 1 : 2
                series.splice(j, 1);
            }
        } else {
            i = dataLength;
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4pth15yf/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.lineWidth